# 8 Precept Commentaries?

Tags: theravada, reference-request, eight-precepts

Would like some suggestions on books/authors/resources for commentaries on keeping and maintaining the 8 and 10 precepts. Haven't found this question answered elsewhere. Am already aware of what the precepts are, just asking for ideas on how to support their practice in everyday situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good commentary on the eight precepts [here](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanavara/uposatha.html) in the Questions and Answers format, originally written in Thai by Ven. Ñanavara Thera and translated into English by Ven. Kantasilo.

Comment: I recommend this best answer (in english). Because this book based on pali canon. The reader can uses the word in book to search more resource in pali in the future.